# Converting Delphi Indy v9 code to v10

Tags: delphi, email, indy10

I'm having trouble with the code below that refers to `StoredPathName`.  As Indy 10 doesn't use `StoredPathName`, I'm not sure how to change this code to adjust from V9 to V10.  The code below wasn't written by me and I'm still a newbie when it comes to this type of code, so I'd appreciate a code example showing how to correct the problem if possible.

```
vlist:TStringList;

...
for j:=numEmails downto 1 do
  begin
    Msg.Clear;
    Retrieve(j,Msg);

    for k:=0 to Msg.MessageParts.Count-1 do
      with Msg.MessageParts[k] do
        if Msg.messageParts[k] is TIdAttachmentFile then
          begin
            //Get the name of the file that was sent.
            aname := TIdAttachmentFile(Msg.MessageParts[k]).FileName;

            if SameText(aname,ExtractFilename(PacketFilename))
            and FileExists(Longfilename(StoredPathName)) then
              begin
                //Read attachment and do call-back if defined.
                vlist.LoadfromFile(LongFilename(StoredPathName));

                if assigned(OnReceive) then
                  OnReceive;
              end
          end;
  end;

Disconnect;

except
  on E:Exception do
    result := E.Message;
end;
```

Also one other bit of code was... `Connect(9000);`
Since 9000 wasn't an allowed argument I just changed it to `Connect;` Is that OK?

Comment: In Indy 9, the parameter to `Connect()` was the `ConnectTimeout`. In Indy 10, that was moved its own property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoredPathName is a property that was moved from TIdMessagePart to TIdAttachmentFile. If you change the code to do a type cast at the top it should all work.

change this:

```
  with Msg.MessageParts[k] do
    if Msg.messageParts[k] is TIdAttachmentFile then
```

to:

```
  if Msg.messageParts[k] is TIdAttachmentFile then
    with TIdAttachmentFile(Msg.MessageParts[k]) do
```